# How to take bengali input from user via GUI in ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, https

I want to implement printf, scanf function to take Bengali utf-8 input or to show bengali utf-8 output. But ubuntu terminal does not show it properly.
 For scanf, I am thinking to create a pop-up window and take Bengali input from user.

Please provide me some code which create pop-up window, take bengali input from user ( need to show it properly ), save it in some file.
Any open-source linux based tool or any programming language is acceptable. But I will prefer to use in-built gui in ubuntu with shell programming.

Show it properly means :-
It should not show as given in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxkSL.png), it should show like this "আমি বক্তৃতা দিচ্ছি"

Comment: Bengali supported javascript based user interface is also preferable. I need a sample code for any case.

Comment: Use `electron` to build a javascript-based GUI app for ubuntu